# Не выводит изображение в html странице для орезки изображения

Tags: django

Мне нужно при добавлении картинки отобразить её что бы пользователь мог её обрезать как ему нужно и в последующем сохранить её как фото профиля Инструкцию по планину орезки (не надо )
Settings настроил все статические папки там всё в порядке проверено!
Помогите пж в интернете инфы не нашёл и ChatGPT не помог

Не выводит картинку которую я добавляю в форме 'выберите файл' нажимаю добавить а там пустой img
"<img src="" alt="Uploaded Image"->""

### urls.py

```
path('test', views.upload_image, name='test'),
```

### views.py

```
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            return render(request, 'app/preview_image.html', {'image': image})
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'app/upload_image.html', {'form': form})
```

### forms.py

```
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

### preview_image.html

```
<body>
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="Uploaded Image">
</body>
```

### upload_image.html

```
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</body>
```